In positive education, what phrase follows the emotional validation?
I’m watching a course on positive parenting and secure attachment, where the instructor emphasizes the importance of "validating the child’s emotions." As an example, they mention a situation where the child wants to have ice cream for breakfast, and after denying it, our job as parents "is not to avoid their frustration, but to acknowledge it." So, what we need to do is maintain boundaries and then empathize by saying things like "I know you were really looking forward to that ice cream" or "You’re feeling a bit disappointed."
When I was a child, the conversation would have been "You can’t have ice cream for breakfast," followed by "because I said so" or "just because." Then, the older family members from my generation, like cousins who now have kids aged 8-10, would say "You can’t have ice cream for breakfast," followed by a lengthy attempt to reason with the child, "because it’s not healthy," "because you already have your cereal," etc.
My question is, exactly following the positive parenting methodology and the approach recommended by the course instructor, how does the conversation continue after the phrases that validate emotions? What exactly follows after "I know you were really looking forward to that ice cream"?

Your book must have examples. What does the instructor say? Now I'm really curious...  Also, "I know you were really looking forward to that ice cream" isn't usually a first response...How did it get there? Did someone say it was a great idea and they could have it? If an adult in charge said it (e.g. the other parent), then the child gets ice cream for breakfast, and you take it up with the other adult in charge..
TL;DR: How you follow up the validation is not critical; the validation is.
Compare the two scenarios, both the first time the child asks for ice cream:

Parent: What would you like for breakfast today?
Child: Ice cream!
Parent: Normal people don't eat ice cream for breakfast. It's not healthy.

This (and any number of other answers) implies that the child is somehow abnormal/dumb/silly/less-than for wanting ice cream for breakfast. If that's the message one wants to send, it succeeds. Repeating this kind of message in a hundred different ways reinforces that message.

Parent: What would you like for breakfast today?
Child: Ice cream!
Parent: You and me both; ice cream is delicious! But breakfast is an important meal; it has to give you energy the whole morning. As good as it tastes, ice cream doesn't do that. [Age dependent: You need protein, some fats, and long-lasting carbohydrates in the morning.] So, something like oatmeal and fruit, or toast with peanut butter and bananas will help you feel good all morning. What do you think? Want toast with bananas and PB?

This (and similar answers) doesn't send the message that the kid is weird or silly for wanting ice cream for breakfast. It validates that it's an understandable desire, and even further, that the parent can relate. Then education follows (not the same as a lecture) the first time. If the request continues, the education part can be cut shorter.
Validation followed by invalidation isn't positive parenting. It's sending mixed messages.

Parent: What would you like for breakfast today?
Child: Ice cream!
Parent: Ice cream is delicious, but that's a bad idea. What do you really want?
Child: Ice cream!
Parent: Stop messing around, we don't have time for this. If you can't make good decisions, I won't ask you what you want; I'll pick for you.

The point is to respond in ways that don't demean the child in any way. Then refer to previous conversations, and build on the good responses the child has made in the past.

What would you like for breakfast today?
Child: Ice cream!
Parent: Sounds yummy, but I think you know why that's not best for breakfast. Yesterday you made a great choice. Do you want what you had yesterday?

What if the child is playing around, insisting on ice cream?

(After first go round) Child: I want ice cream!
Parent: Let's have a do-over.
Child: I don't want anything.
Parent: Ok, I'm making scrambled eggs and toast. You can have some if you want.

A do-over is letting the child know they aren't going to have the requested item without an unnecessarily harsh response ("Quit messing around!")
Positive parenting isn't black or white, always do this and never do that. There are many shades in between. At first it takes a lot of thought and self-correction (and apologies) to get it right-ish. Just think about your words, how you want to be treated, then do your best to treat your child lovingly instead of as less-than (less wise/less experienced/less reasonable/less self-regulated than we adults.) After a while, it becomes pretty much second nature.
Then the kids reach their teens.
Not sure how you got there, but I'll give an alternate frustrating scenario that happened with me and my kids: You're at an amusement park, and the child finds $10. They want to go to a store immediately to spend it. Parent: I know you really want to go to the store and buy something with the money you found. It's frustrating to wait; I understand that. It's exciting to find money, isn't it? You imagine all kinds of fun things you can buy. But we committed to this day in the park, which is also fun, so we do that first. We can go to the store in the morning. Will that do? It's just basically treating your child the way you would want to be treated if you were the child that wasn't in charge of their agenda.

Also, ice cream for breakfast once in a while won't kill anyone. Preferably on the weekend, so the child doesn't crash and burn in school, where it becomes the teacher's responsibility to manage.

This is a good answer. In general, most of the ways parents traditionally react is because they don't want to make the effort of providing a real response, to actually explain the decision. It conserves effort. But if you get in the habit of actually explaining your decisions to your kids just like you would explain them to anyone, you'd be surprised how agreeable they become, and how much they learn. To me these situations are learning opportunities for your kids, take advantage of them.
